# Trying to write quotes (") in xml using java

Tags: java, dom

I have a long string which contains ~" & "~ etc.
but when I am trying to write it in xml the o/p is: `~&quot`
please suggest a way to write the complete string including "(double quotes)

Below are my code:

```
for(String str:Parser.queryList){
                        Element query = doc.createElement("query");
                        view.appendChild(screen);
                        screen.appendChild(query);
                        query.setAttribute("query", str);
            }
output: OP =~&quot;=~&quot;
```

Comment: Show your code and your output. We can't suggest how to fix something if you don't show the code that produces the wrong output. Secondly, it depends on where in the XML this is. If it is inside an attribute value of an element, then there's no way to avoid encoding the double quotes because a double quote closes the attribute value. But in  XML body text, you can just have double quotes. It's not clear whether you mean attribute value or body text, hence: show the XML.

Comment: Also your title doesn't match your question, since you're asking about the double quote character ("), not the tilde (~)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: Tildes are sometimes used as a kind of placeholder character; for example, in many bilingual dictionaries, an entry for e.g. **ball** will have a subentry for e.g. **have a ~**, meaning "have a ball". I think the OP has probably mis-extrapolated from that, and meant something along the lines of `"..."` or `"___"`, that is, quotation marks with something unspecified in between.

Comment: It's not possible to leave the double quotes unescaped in attribute values (your code shows that you are using attribute values), since that would result in invalid XML - or valid XML with a different meaning than you intended